# Keychain Assistant does not create public/private key pair, and my distribution certificates fail codesign verification

Tags: keychain, private-key, public-key

My certificates were expiring today (and at this point, it's totally expired), so I set out to renew the certificates. But the problem is, I can't get matching private/public keys for proper code-signing verification with the renewed certificates.  All I've read says keychain will automatically create matching public/private keys, but it's not doing it for me.  I am totally stumped and I don't know what I can do at this point.  Please help.  Here's what I've done so far:

1)  I revoked the certificates from Apple Developer > iOS Provisioning Portal > Certificates > Developer and Distribution tabs.

2)  I launched Keychain Access.app from Applications > Utilities.

3)  I removed all outdated certificates, and eventually removed everything except for Apple Code Signing Certification Authority, Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority, Dashboard Advisory and Software Signing.  (By the way, I have no idea what this "Software Signing" certificate is for, but it won't be expiring until 2015, I'm reluctant to delete it without knowing what it would do to the system if I deleted it.)

4)  I generated CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest via Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate From a Certificate Authority

5)  Got the CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest on desktop.  (At this point, I check the Keychain, and I still don't see my private or public keys.

6)  I submit the CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest at Apple Developer > iOS Provisioning Portal > Certificates > Developer and Distribution tabs.

7)  I download the certificates, install them to keychain, and it looks like my certificates are now renewed for another year.

8)  I renew all provisioning profiles.

9)  I retrieve them to my Xcode.

10)  I generate new distribution build, then I get the warning that "Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate."

11)  I look at the Keychain again, and I don't see my private or public keys.

12)  Well, I exported p12 file a year ago.  So, okay, I start all over again (i.e., take the steps 1, 2 and 3.)  Then I import the p12 file.  Now I see my private key in my Keychain.

13)  I then resume with step 4 above (i.e., get the CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest via Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate From a Certificate Authority)

14)  I continue on with steps 5 through 8.  Just to make sure, I reboot my machine again.  Then I check my Keychain, and public key is still missing, and taking steps 9 and 10 results exactly the same.

What am I doing wrong?  What should I do to fix this problem?  I'd so appreciate any and all help.

---

EDIT:  I'm not entirely sure which steps I took actually ended up fixing this, but I got it working now. Main thing was, deleting everything from keychain and look for possible cause all over the web, and and I did read this thread too:

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060318124936642

And run these commands:

sudo systemkeychain -vfcC

systemkeychain -vt

I also continued to look for how to repair keychain, run disk utility, repairing any and all permission issues, etc.

And eventually, my keychain access app started working as expected again, and it finally generated both private and public keys.  Ahhhh.  Once it did that, everything else worked fine, doing the steps I took earlier.